# Azure Classic To Resource To Standard

Tags: azure, standards, azure-load-balancer

I am completing a Classic to Resource move for a customer. I have this piece down fairly well. This customer is using a Classic Load Balancer. I need to use a Standard Load Balancer due to the network configuration.

I also need to keep the existing IP's on the classic resource. I can't convert the a basic IP to a Standard IP sku. Is this something I can do during the Classic to Resource Conversion? I haven't been able to find any documentation to back up that thought.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly and you want to keep the old/current IPs and don't want to convert them from basic to standard then the answer is:

IP addresses aren't affected when migrating a resource from Classic (ASM - Azure Service Manager) to Resource (ARM - Azure Resource Manager).

Here is a link that lists supported an unsupported features during migration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#unsupported-features-and-configurations

Comment: The issue is related to the SKU of the IP address at time of migration. Due to the fact standard IP's didn't exist in classic, I want to migrate my IP to be a standard IP.

Comment: Yes, you can convert the basic IPs to standard after you do the migration. @SecretlyCool